# Invoking gcc -pthread under ExtUtils::MakeMaker

Tags: perl, gcc, pthreads, makemaker

What's the right way to specify compilation and linking with `-pthread` (*not* `-lpthread`) in a Makefile.PL?

It's my understanding that gcc ought to be invoked with `-pthread` when building against pthreads, as this flag expands to the correct platform-specific flags for both compilation and linking.

I started with:

```
use Config;
my %mm = ( NAME => 'Local::Example::Pthreaded', ...);
...
if ($Config{ccname} eq 'gcc') {
  $mm{DEFINE} = join(' ', '-pthread', $mm{DEFINE});   # ??? in the right place?
  $mm{LIBS}   = ['-pthread'];                         # XXX ignored!

}
WriteMakefile(%mm);
```

However, I'm not sure that the DEFINE usage puts `-pthread` in the right place.  (User DEFINEs appears at the end of the compilation command.)  Moreover, the LIBS argument is ignored because it doesn't look like a typical `-l`/`-L` linker argument:  "Unrecognized argument in LIBS ignored: '-pthread'".