# gcc arguments: -pthread. What does it do?

Tags: multithreading, gcc, pthreads, compiler-flags

I'm getting started with multi-thread programming using gcc under Debian 8. I've successfully written and run a multi-threaded test app (foobar.c), but I'm confused by the Makefile (copied from an example). In particular, the command that works is

```
gcc foobar.c -o foobar -pthread
```

I'm confused by "-pthread". is that

(a) an option "-p" with value "thread", or
(b) an argument "-pthread" ?

if either case, what is it actually doing? Including some library? Including some object? Setting some other option?

BTW - A similar question [15929739](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929739) was asked but never answered. Question [20924412](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924412) was not helpful either.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23250863/694576

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html):

> **`-pthread`**
>   Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library. This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.

To be specific, as of GCC 6.2.1, `-pthread` will:

- `#define _REENTRANT 1`
- Add `-lpthread` to link against `libpthread`

How do I know this, you ask?

**What preprocessor flags are added?**

Let's [dump the preprocessor defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines) and compare them:

```
$ diff <(gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null) <(gcc -pthread -dM -E - < /dev/null)
> #define _REENTRANT 1
```

**What linker options are added?**

Let's [dump the ld options passed by GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170809/how-to-get-gcc-linker-command) and compare them:

```
diff <(gcc -### -o foo empty.c 2>&1) <(gcc -### -pthread -o foo empty.c 2>&1)
```

The output here is a bit more verbose, but if we ignore the temporary filename differences, we find:

- `-lpthread`
- `"-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread"`

Comment: Yes, I see that but still unclear. What is defined for the preprocessor? What is linked? Sorry for being such a dummy.